# replaceAll is not a function warning in VSCode even though im using target ES2021

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tsconfig

In a vue project, this is my tsconfig file:

```
{
   "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
   "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "src/**/*.json"],
   "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
      "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2021",
      "module": "ESNext",
      "lib":["ES2021", "DOM"], <-- If i remove this line, I get warnings in vue and .ts files
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
      "composite": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
         "@/*": ["./src/*"]
      },
      "allowJs": true,
      "outDir": "target",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "types": ["vite/client"],
      "strictNullChecks": false,
   }
 }
```

If my target is ES2021, I was expecting to be able to use ES2021 features without getting errors (ex: "resresr sdf".replaceAll(" ", "") **is not a function**).
However it seems that I **have to add** "lib":["ES2021", "DOM"] to get rid of the error. Why do I have to add lib 2021?

Note that I am using Volar extension with takeover mode (https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode) and have disabled Typescript vscode extension as per their recommendation. However before I did this, I was also getting the same warning.

I have tried restarting the Volar server in between making the changes and still no luck...

[image: TS error showing]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"module" and "target" are compilerOptions properties but you've placed them outside of compilerOptions, it should be:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "module": "ESNext",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply :). Sorry i actually moved that out as a failed experiment. Even when it lives inside, it still doesnt work without lib.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a band-aid solution, but an explicit library target specified with [the triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) should make things work on a per-file basis. So, until you figure out the config, I'd try adding the following line to the top of your file:

```
\\\ <reference lib="es2021" />
```